# How to load the correct KML according to location?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml

I have 15 kml files and I have a map from google map api, still I haven't found some way to put the correct kml from 15 kml files that I have according if the location are within kml area. Its possible to do that?

Example: I have this kml file in my map but if i am in other location but within kml area how can i check this one new coordinate is within the kml area?

[image: example map]

One try that i made was extract 'sublocality' from my responde and in array put all sublocalitys from this area, the problem for this i the quantityt form each districts (like  80 subocalities each kml)

```
    geocoder.geocode(
        {'location': latlng},
            function(results, status) {
                if (status === 'OK') {
                    for (var i = 0; i < results[0].address_components.length; i++){
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            if (results[0]) {
                               for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                                   //alert(results[i].types[0]+','+results[i].types[1]+','+results[i].address_components[0].long_name)
                                   //district how i get them
                                   if (results[i].types[0]=='political' && results[i].types[1]=='sublocality' ){
                                       district = results[i].address_components[0].long_name;
                                       console.log("Estas en el distrito: " + district);
                                       console.log(district);
                                       console.log(results);
                                   }
                               }
                            }
                            else {console.log("No reverse geocode results.")}
                        }
                        else {console.log("Geocoder failed: " + status)}
                    }
                }});
/*For get district*/
    
    
    var distrito_2=["Peublito","San Jose 2","Independencia"];
    var src_aux=null;
    
    for(var i=0; i<distrito_1.length; i++){
        if(district==distrito_1[i]){
            console.log(distrito_1[i] + " Estas en el Distrito 1"); 
            src_aux='https://www.dropbox.com/s/u8knmtfsp4bhnkd/Distrito_1.kml?dl=1';
        }
    }
    for(var j=0; j<distrito_2.length; j++){
        if(district==distrito_2[j]){
            console.log(distrito_2[j] + " Estas en el Distrito 4"); 
            src_aux='https://www.dropbox.com/s/e3t3u4y3ytxgkj1/Distrito_4.kml?dl=1';
        }
    }
    
    
    
    
    var src=src_aux;
    var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(src, {
          suppressInfoWindows: true,
          preserveViewport: false,
          map: map
        });
```

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this example:](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geocodePointInPolygon_linktoB.html?address=Vistas%20De%20San%20Pablo&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/Distrito_1.kml)?

Comment: Or [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geocodePointInPolygon_linktoB.html?address=San%20Jose%20El%20Alto&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/Distrito_1.kml,http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/Distrito_4.kml) (2 kml files loaded)

Comment: @geocodezip is more like second example, only missing put  if i choose a point within the green kml (one location like San Jose el Alto or  Lomas de Mechaca or other location contain within green kml) that only appears this kml  in green and not the blue kml and if i choose a location that contain kml in blue that only appear the kml in blue and disappear the green kml

Comment: So like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geocodePointInPolygon_linktoC.html?address=Altos%20de%20San%20Pablo&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/Distrito_1.kml,http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/Distrito_4.kml) (blue polygon) and [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geocodePointInPolygon_linktoC.html?address=San%20Jose%20El%20Alto&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/Distrito_1.kml,http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/Distrito_4.kml) (the orangish polygon)

Comment: @geocodezip is like  your penultimate answer,  how do you to do that?

Answer (score 0):

One option is something like [this example](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geocodePointInPolygon_linktoC.html?address=San%20Jose%20El%20Alto&filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/Distrito_1.kml,http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/Distrito_4.kml)

[image: geocoded "Altos de San Pable" in blue polygon]
[image: geocoded "" in blue polygon" in other polygon]

This is implemented using the [geoxml3 library](https://github.com/geocodezip/geoxml3) to parse the KML to native Google Maps Javascript API v3 objects, then process through them to determine if the point is in one of the polygons, then show that KML, hiding all others
(disclaimer, I maintain that library)

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/1pfguym7/) (only one polygon from each KML)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geoXml = null;
var map = null;
var geocoder = null;
var toggleState = 1;
var infowindow = null;
var marker = null;
var address = null;

function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
  });

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: {
      lat: 20.644352,
      lng: -100.415056
    },
    zoom: 13,
  });
  geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
    map: map,
    singleInfoWindow: true,
    infoWindow: infowindow,
    zoom: false
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(geoXml, "parsed", function() {
    if (address) setTimeout(function() {
      showAddress(address);
    }, 500);
  });
  geoXml.parseKmlString(Distrito_1_kml);
  geoXml.parseKmlString(Distrito_4_kml);
  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function() {
    for (var j = 0; j < geoXml.docs.length; j++) {
      for (var i = 0; i < geoXml.docs[j].placemarks.length; i++) {
        var placemark = geoXml.docs[j].placemarks[i];
        if (placemark.polygon) {
          google.maps.event.addListener(placemark.polygon, 'click', clickHandler);
        }
      }
    }
  });

  function clickHandler(evt) {
    var contentString = "click<br>Outside Area";
    var point = evt.latLng;
    contentString += "<br>" + point.toUrlValue(6);
    map.setCenter(point);
    if (marker && marker.setMap) marker.setMap(null);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: point
    });
    contentString = findAndDisplayKml("click", point, contentString);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(contentString);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(marker, "click");
  }

}

function showAddress(address) {
  var contentString = address + "<br>Outside Area";
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var point = results[0].geometry.location;
      contentString += "<br>" + point;
      map.setCenter(point);
      if (marker && marker.setMap) marker.setMap(null);
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: point
      });
      contentString = findAndDisplayKml(address, point, contentString);
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infowindow.setContent(contentString);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      google.maps.event.trigger(marker, "click");
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}

function findAndDisplayKml(address, point, contentString) {
  for (var j = 0; j < geoXml.docs.length; j++) {
    geoXml.hideDocument(geoXml.docs[j]);
    for (var i = 0; i < geoXml.docs[j].gpolygons.length; i++) {
      if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, geoXml.docs[j].gpolygons[i])) {
        contentString = address + "<br>" + geoXml.docs[j].placemarks[i].name;
        contentString += "<br>" + point + "<br>polygon#" + i;
        geoXml.showDocument(geoXml.docs[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  return contentString;
}

window.initialize = initialize;
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
var Distrito_1_kml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"><Document><name>Distrito_1</name><Style id="poly-0288D1-2000-76-normal"><LineStyle><color>ffd18802</color><width>2</width></LineStyle><PolyStyle><color>4cd18802</color><fill>1</fill><outline>1</outline></PolyStyle></Style><Style id="poly-0288D1-2000-76-highlight"><LineStyle><color>ffd18802</color><width>3</width></LineStyle><PolyStyle><color>4cd18802</color><fill>1</fill><outline>1</outline></PolyStyle></Style><StyleMap id="poly-0288D1-2000-76"><Pair><key>normal</key><styleUrl>#poly-0288D1-2000-76-normal</styleUrl></Pair><Pair><key>highlight</key><styleUrl>#poly-0288D1-2000-76-highlight</styleUrl></Pair></StyleMap><Placemark><name>278</name><description><![CDATA[SECCIÓN: 278<br>ENTIDAD: Querétaro<br>MUNICIPIO: 14 - Santiago de Querétaro<br>DISTRITO LOCAL: 1]]></description><styleUrl>#poly-0288D1-2000-76</styleUrl><ExtendedData><Data name="SECCIÓN"><value>278</value></Data><Data name="ENTIDAD"><value>Querétaro</value></Data><Data name="MUNICIPIO"><value>14 - Santiago de Querétaro</value></Data><Data name="DISTRITO LOCAL"><value>1</value></Data></ExtendedData><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><tessellate>1</tessellate><coordinates> -100.409668,20.629613,0 -100.409679,20.629712,0 -100.409677,20.630144,0 -100.409677,20.630171,0 -100.409736,20.630203,0 -100.40974,20.630463,0 -100.409766,20.631484,0 -100.408865,20.631579,0 -100.40774,20.631686,0 -100.406707,20.631787,0 -100.406284,20.631817,0 -100.406178,20.631825,0 -100.40615,20.631935,0 -100.406067,20.632246,0 -100.405943,20.632227,0 -100.40592,20.632289,0 -100.405889,20.632386,0 -100.405724,20.633048,0 -100.405695,20.633181,0 -100.405672,20.633451,0 -100.405676,20.633638,0 -100.4057,20.633793,0 -100.405738,20.633977,0 -100.405812,20.634262,0 -100.405874,20.634465,0 -100.405961,20.634735,0 -100.405996,20.634858,0 -100.406049,20.635118,0 -100.406072,20.635331,0 -100.406063,20.635521,0 -100.406045,20.635705,0 -100.406024,20.635952,0 -100.405983,20.636413,0 -100.40598,20.63645,0 -100.40595,20.636858,0 -100.405895,20.637401,0 -100.405889,20.637469,0 -100.40587,20.637762,0 -100.405842,20.638065,0 -100.405751,20.639173,0 -100.405732,20.639402,0 -100.405704,20.639709,0 -100.405628,20.640562,0 -100.405582,20.641011,0 -100.405564,20.641259,0 -100.405446,20.642328,0 -100.405318,20.643219,0 -100.405374,20.643227,0 -100.405399,20.643231,0 -100.405456,20.643239,0 -100.406037,20.643395,0 -100.406437,20.643468,0 -100.407015,20.64359,0 -100.40704,20.643685,0 -100.408085,20.643885,0 -100.409438,20.644105,0 -100.409939,20.644173,0 -100.409878,20.644563,0 -100.409818,20.644919,0 -100.409751,20.64538,0 -100.41022,20.645442,0 -100.41111,20.645431,0 -100.411504,20.645414,0 -100.412221,20.645394,0 -100.412427,20.645388,0 -100.412962,20.645388,0 -100.41305,20.645388,0 -100.413431,20.645386,0 -100.414645,20.645386,0 -100.415518,20.645369,0 -100.416074,20.645369,0 -100.416259,20.645391,0 -100.416281,20.646105,0 -100.416282,20.646274,0 -100.41605,20.648333,0 -100.416051,20.648501,0 -100.41727,20.648281,0 -100.41769,20.648367,0 -100.418161,20.648372,0 -100.418367,20.648374,0 -100.419087,20.648353,0 -100.419149,20.648262,0 -100.419288,20.648107,0 -100.419407,20.647987,0 -100.419611,20.647847,0 -100.41978,20.647777,0 -100.420391,20.647573,0 -100.420984,20.647497,0 -100.422092,20.647409,0 -100.424483,20.647507,0 -100.424309,20.647752,0 -100.424257,20.647935,0 -100.424227,20.648161,0 -100.424256,20.648305,0 -100.424305,20.648424,0 -100.424361,20.64856,0 -100.424457,20.648686,0 -100.424571,20.648801,0 -100.424734,20.648895,0 -100.424901,20.64899,0 -100.425074,20.649078,0 -100.425298,20.649134,0 -100.425556,20.649144,0 -100.425808,20.649116,0 -100.426017,20.64907,0 -100.426157,20.649002,0 -100.426322,20.648911,0 -100.426478,20.64881,0 -100.426633,20.648699,0 -100.42674,20.648567,0 -100.426825,20.648425,0 -100.426879,20.648276,0 -100.426909,20.648128,0 -100.426976,20.647611,0 -100.427061,20.647082,0 -100.427129,20.646682,0 -100.427177,20.646407,0 -100.427267,20.646006,0 -100.427389,20.645516,0 -100.427424,20.645349,0 -100.427566,20.644798,0 -100.427772,20.644361,0 -100.427917,20.644017,0 -100.428127,20.64377,0 -100.428267,20.643654,0 -100.428392,20.643547,0 -100.4285,20.643468,0 -100.428463,20.64357,0 -100.428438,20.643755,0 -100.428414,20.643993,0 -100.428422,20.644287,0 -100.428483,20.646538,0 -100.428548,20.649113,0 -100.42862,20.652588,0 -100.428633,20.652888,0 -100.428496,20.652953,0 -100.428183,20.652938,0 -100.427874,20.65296,0 -100.427573,20.653128,0 -100.427196,20.65325,0 -100.426666,20.653255,0 -100.42619,20.653591,0 -100.42584,20.653974,0 -100.42539,20.654381,0 -100.424962,20.654527,0 -100.424534,20.65465,0 -100.424082,20.654796,0 -100.421918,20.655855,0 -100.421962,20.656975,0 -100.42399,20.656872,0 -100.424178,20.656966,0 -100.424443,20.657054,0 -100.424708,20.657237,0 -100.424849,20.657355,0 -100.42493,20.657424,0 -100.424741,20.657959,0 -100.42454,20.658633,0 -100.423783,20.65966,0 -100.423629,20.660163,0 -100.423832,20.660401,0 -100.424282,20.661192,0 -100.424526,20.661691,0 -100.424871,20.662522,0 -100.425065,20.662688,0 -100.425891,20.663295,0 -100.426348,20.663612,0 -100.426923,20.663991,0 -100.427301,20.663709,0 -100.427383,20.663971,0 -100.427835,20.664538,0 -100.428085,20.664345,0 -100.428486,20.663879,0 -100.428889,20.663352,0 -100.429273,20.662799,0 -100.430088,20.662758,0 -100.430745,20.662683,0 -100.431194,20.662662,0 -100.43144,20.662651,0 -100.431967,20.662559,0 -100.432337,20.662451,0 -100.432465,20.662276,0 -100.432741,20.662077,0 -100.432827,20.662015,0 -100.432874,20.661981,0 -100.432824,20.661519,0 -100.432794,20.661265,0 -100.432722,20.66063,0 -100.432678,20.660225,0 -100.432622,20.659696,0 -100.43259,20.659398,0 -100.432569,20.659193,0 -100.4325,20.658553,0 -100.432471,20.658277,0 -100.432402,20.65765,0 -100.432359,20.657263,0 -100.43226,20.656375,0 -100.43216,20.655417,0 -100.43211,20.654995,0 -100.432048,20.65448,0 -100.432008,20.654025,0 -100.431916,20.653163,0 -100.431871,20.652729,0 -100.431801,20.652055,0 -100.431766,20.65171,0 -100.431701,20.651094,0 -100.431644,20.650602,0 -100.431541,20.649636,0 -100.43143,20.648652,0 -100.431375,20.648168,0 -100.43133,20.647664,0 -100.431298,20.647266,0 -100.431288,20.647142,0 -100.431281,20.647064,0 -100.43128,20.647045,0 -100.43127,20.646958,0 -100.431249,20.64678,0 -100.431246,20.646762,0 -100.431021,20.644856,0 -100.43101,20.644763,0 -100.430944,20.644197,0 -100.430865,20.643219,0 -100.430858,20.643095,0 -100.430855,20.643058,0 -100.430853,20.643017,0 -100.43081,20.642347,0 -100.430806,20.642283,0 -100.430804,20.642253,0 -100.4308,20.642197,0 -100.430797,20.642146,0 -100.430795,20.642117,0 -100.430793,20.642089,0 -100.430709,20.641467,0 -100.430668,20.641084,0 -100.430649,20.640904,0 -100.430644,20.640856,0 -100.430482,20.640176,0 -100.430299,20.639634,0 -100.42995,20.638893,0 -100.429937,20.638867,0 -100.429467,20.637874,0 -100.429077,20.637082,0 -100.428739,20.636372,0 -100.428481,20.635831,0 -100.427989,20.634822,0 -100.42776,20.634325,0 -100.427287,20.633299,0 -100.427198,20.633104,0 -100.426599,20.631688,0 -100.426416,20.631228,0 -100.426409,20.63121,0 -100.425877,20.629881,0 -100.425826,20.629755,0 -100.425815,20.629726,0 -100.425786,20.62965,0 -100.425422,20.628688,0 -100.425336,20.628494,0 -100.42525,20.6283,0 -100.424608,20.626793,0 -100.424455,20.626424,0 -100.423544,20.624231,0 -100.423324,20.623653,0 -100.423077,20.623005,0 -100.422868,20.622456,0 -100.422816,20.622325,0 -100.422801,20.622287,0 -100.42277,20.62221,0 -100.422432,20.622165,0 -100.42207,20.622108,0 -100.42132,20.621991,0 -100.420547,20.621882,0 -100.42039,20.62186,0 -100.419795,20.621778,0 -100.419674,20.621761,0 -100.419569,20.621747,0 -100.419549,20.621743,0 -100.419517,20.621738,0 -100.419429,20.621722,0 -100.41928,20.621696,0 -100.419197,20.621682,0 -100.418642,20.621585,0 -100.418609,20.621581,0 -100.418569,20.621576,0 -100.418475,20.621564,0 -100.417963,20.6215,0 -100.417891,20.621491,0 -100.417835,20.621484,0 -100.41776,20.621471,0 -100.417643,20.621452,0 -100.417184,20.621376,0 -100.41716,20.621372,0 -100.416811,20.621313,0 -100.416738,20.621302,0 -100.416712,20.621472,0 -100.417641,20.621598,0 -100.418602,20.621763,0 -100.418722,20.622057,0 -100.41787,20.622215,0 -100.418221,20.623157,0 -100.418466,20.623771,0 -100.41836,20.623797,0 -100.418067,20.623868,0 -100.41759,20.623966,0 -100.417702,20.62427,0 -100.417844,20.624656,0 -100.417312,20.624797,0 -100.417357,20.625136,0 -100.417388,20.625471,0 -100.41742,20.625469,0 -100.417734,20.625446,0 -100.418001,20.625418,0 -100.418268,20.625389,0 -100.41831,20.625836,0 -100.418314,20.625884,0 -100.418341,20.626164,0 -100.418372,20.626364,0 -100.418405,20.626574,0 -100.418424,20.626726,0 -100.418436,20.626825,0 -100.418463,20.626916,0 -100.418484,20.626983,0 -100.418588,20.627132,0 -100.418763,20.627254,0 -100.418909,20.627385,0 -100.418941,20.627425,0 -100.419004,20.627503,0 -100.419048,20.627679,0 -100.419063,20.627833,0 -100.419027,20.627957,0 -100.41892,20.628068,0 -100.418668,20.628094,0 -100.418495,20.628112,0 -100.418222,20.628141,0 -100.417921,20.628172,0 -100.4177,20.628195,0 -100.41773,20.628435,0 -100.416789,20.628549,0 -100.416545,20.628577,0 -100.416156,20.62862,0 -100.415776,20.628663,0 -100.41539,20.628706,0 -100.415005,20.628749,0 -100.414648,20.628789,0 -100.414655,20.629057,0 -100.41466,20.629217,0 -100.414663,20.629376,0 -100.413013,20.629444,0 -100.412907,20.628874,0 -100.412831,20.628879,0 -100.412811,20.628881,0 -100.412802,20.628818,0 -100.412744,20.628826,0 -100.412641,20.62884,0 -100.412229,20.628887,0 -100.412207,20.62889,0 -100.412109,20.628901,0 -100.412067,20.628906,0 -100.411789,20.628938,0 -100.411767,20.62894,0 -100.411679,20.62895,0 -100.411642,20.628954,0 -100.411394,20.628983,0 -100.411326,20.628991,0 -100.411107,20.629016,0 -100.410991,20.629029,0 -100.410692,20.6295,0 -100.41041,20.629968,0 -100.410392,20.629997,0 -100.409668,20.629613,0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></Placemark></Document></kml>';

var Distrito_4_kml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"><Document><name>Distrito_4</name><Style id="poly-817717-2000-76-normal"><LineStyle><color>ff177781</color><width>2</width></LineStyle><PolyStyle><color>4c177781</color><fill>1</fill><outline>1</outline></PolyStyle></Style><Style id="poly-817717-2000-76-highlight"><LineStyle><color>ff177781</color><width>3</width></LineStyle><PolyStyle><color>4c177781</color><fill>1</fill><outline>1</outline></PolyStyle></Style><StyleMap id="poly-817717-2000-76"><Pair><key>normal</key><styleUrl>#poly-817717-2000-76-normal</styleUrl></Pair><Pair><key>highlight</key><styleUrl>#poly-817717-2000-76-highlight</styleUrl></Pair></StyleMap><Placemark><name>873</name><description><![CDATA[SECCIÓN: 873<br>ENTIDAD: Querétaro<br>DISTRITO LOCAL: 4<br>MUNICIPIO: 14 - Querétaro]]></description><styleUrl>#poly-817717-2000-76</styleUrl><ExtendedData><Data name="SECCIÓN"><value>873</value></Data><Data name="ENTIDAD"><value>Querétaro</value></Data><Data name="DISTRITO LOCAL"><value>4</value></Data><Data name="MUNICIPIO"><value>14 - Querétaro</value></Data></ExtendedData><Polygon><outerBoundaryIs><LinearRing><tessellate>1</tessellate><coordinates> -100.387018,20.653116,0 -100.387013,20.653004,0 -100.387008,20.652893,0 -100.386972,20.652406,0 -100.386918,20.651922,0 -100.386901,20.651777,0 -100.386856,20.651331,0 -100.386808,20.650925,0 -100.387001,20.650915,0 -100.38741,20.650885,0 -100.387892,20.650845,0 -100.387829,20.650077,0 -100.387819,20.649967,0 -100.387802,20.649779,0 -100.38775,20.64929,0 -100.387733,20.64913,0 -100.387688,20.64866,0 -100.387633,20.648093,0 -100.387427,20.64801,0 -100.38727,20.648222,0 -100.387047,20.648519,0 -100.386905,20.648699,0 -100.386793,20.648818,0 -100.386505,20.648618,0 -100.386161,20.648394,0 -100.385745,20.648144,0 -100.385368,20.647898,0 -100.385093,20.647712,0 -100.384971,20.647704,0 -100.38459,20.647692,0 -100.384169,20.647704,0 -100.383771,20.647707,0 -100.383534,20.647697,0 -100.383451,20.647725,0 -100.383356,20.64777,0 -100.383355,20.647705,0 -100.38272,20.647289,0 -100.382523,20.64716,0 -100.382382,20.647069,0 -100.382193,20.647327,0 -100.38218,20.647254,0 -100.381338,20.64651,0 -100.380943,20.646118,0 -100.380487,20.64562,0 -100.380335,20.645467,0 -100.380254,20.645587,0 -100.38013,20.645799,0 -100.380038,20.645948,0 -100.379893,20.646355,0 -100.379787,20.646673,0 -100.379565,20.647378,0 -100.379476,20.647649,0 -100.379344,20.64806,0 -100.379083,20.648925,0 -100.378938,20.649367,0 -100.37882,20.64977,0 -100.378679,20.650227,0 -100.378551,20.650662,0 -100.377934,20.652708,0 -100.377661,20.653563,0 -100.377527,20.65398,0 -100.377504,20.654161,0 -100.377618,20.654096,0 -100.378376,20.653822,0 -100.379451,20.653702,0 -100.380207,20.653642,0 -100.3805,20.65362,0 -100.380805,20.653597,0 -100.380867,20.653593,0 -100.381008,20.653582,0 -100.381346,20.653557,0 -100.381679,20.653531,0 -100.382206,20.653506,0 -100.382744,20.653452,0 -100.382803,20.653448,0 -100.383057,20.65343,0 -100.383387,20.653405,0 -100.383713,20.65338,0 -100.383815,20.653372,0 -100.38476,20.653302,0 -100.384882,20.653291,0 -100.385975,20.653201,0 -100.387018,20.653116,0</coordinates></LinearRing></outerBoundaryIs></Polygon></Placemark></Document></kml>';
```

```css
#map {
  height: 70%;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Simple Map</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="#" onsubmit="showAddress(this.address.value); return false" style="padding:10px 0px 30px 0px; background:none;">
    <p>
      <label>Address Search</label><br/>
      <input type="text" size="60" id="address" name="address" value="San Jose El Alto" class="address" /><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Search" />(options: San Jose El Alto, Vistas de San Pablo)
    </p>
  </form>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/geocodezip/geoxml3@master/polys/geoxml3.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: How can I search for a location and load only the particular region in map. My kml has all the regions and cities in a country from 4 files. I am using the google places autocomplete to search the particular place.

Comment: That is another question.